# Sonarqube plugin for Eclipse 4.4.0 (Luna) + Java 1.6_0111 not working

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarlint-eclipse

I am new to Sonarqube. I tried to install Sonarqube Eclipse plugin. Installation was successful and restarted Eclipse. But, I could not see Sonar options or view.

I tried both Sonar lint and this

- http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/
- Eclipse : Luna
- Java : 1.6
- Sonar-server : 4.0

Please help me how to get it installed and analyse my project in Eclipse.